# Post requests response returns empty string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to get reponse from the below url. I have tried to get the data using below code, but unfortunately it is returning empty string.

```
url = 'https://covid19index.in/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=21'
params = {
    'action': 'get_wdtable',
    'table_id': 21
    }

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'covid19index.in',
    'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.312051040.1587970650; _gid=GA1.2.1069938183.1587970650; _gat=1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Referer': 'https://covid19index.in/district-wise-cases/',
    'Origin': 'https://covid19index.in'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3))
time.sleep(2)

try:
    content = s.post(url,data= params, headers=headers)
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    try:
        for _ in range(10):
            content= s.post(url,data= params, headers= headers)          
    except:
        print('Failed: ', 'Too many Requets and redirect')
        sys.exit()
```

when i print content.text it returns '' (an empty string)

I have tried all the possible things to get the output.but iwas unable to get the output.If any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: When I open that link https://covid19index.in/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=21 in my browser, I also find an empty page. This is probably the website server not rendering pages. Can you manage to see anything?

Comment: `wp-admin` means you are actually trying to log in to the admin interface of that website - is that intended?

Comment: @Arnaud: Then again, OP does a POST, not a GET, so I think it's not uncommon for it to be an empty page when opened in a browser.

Comment: Makes sense @Ludo21South - by the way I also see no data when looking at browser's inspector for network answers. Could be an authentication issue.

Comment: this is post method we cannot view this on browser. we can see response if we inspect -https://covid19index.in/district-wise-cases/   and navigate to network.@Arnaud @Ludo21South

Comment: @PavanSuvarna: Have you used something like Postman to setup a valid request? This way you can check the results and not worry about coding issues. Might help you to debug setting up the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, using a browser inspector, I could receive data from that server. Here's a working code I got by copying the `cURL` request from my browser to a Python converter https://curl.trillworks.com/

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'wordpress_test_cookie': 'WP+Cookie+check',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.1193786784.1588060314',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.1185668591.1588060314',
    '_gat': '1',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Origin': 'https://covid19index.in',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://covid19index.in/district-wise-cases/',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

params = (
    ('action', 'get_wdtable'),
    ('table_id', '21'),
)

data = {
  'draw': '1',
  'columns[0][data]': '0',
  'columns[0][name]': 'state',
  'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[0][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[0][search][value]': '',
  'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[1][data]': '1',
  'columns[1][name]': 'district',
  'columns[1][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[1][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[1][search][value]': '',
  'columns[1][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[2][data]': '2',
  'columns[2][name]': 'date',
  'columns[2][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[2][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[2][search][value]': '',
  'columns[2][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[3][data]': '3',
  'columns[3][name]': 'date_total',
  'columns[3][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[3][orderable]': 'false',
  'columns[3][search][value]': '',
  'columns[3][search][regex]': 'false',
  'start': '0',
  'length': '-1',
  'search[value]': '',
  'search[regex]': 'false',
  'wdtNonce': 'cee9844d13'
}

response = requests.post('https://covid19index.in/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

And data is reachable:

```
import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(response.content.decode("utf-8"))["data"]                                                                                       
[['Andaman and Nicobar Islands',
  'North and Middle Andaman',
  '27\\/03\\/2020',
  '1'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '26\\/03\\/2020', '1'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '27\\/03\\/2020', '4'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '28\\/03\\/2020', '3'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '30\\/03\\/2020', '1'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '08\\/04\\/2020', '1'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '17\\/04\\/2020', '1'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '18\\/04\\/2020', '2'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '19\\/04\\/2020', '1'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '20\\/04\\/2020', '1'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '21\\/04\\/2020', '1'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '22\\/04\\/2020', '1'],
 ['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', 'South Andaman', '23\\/04\\/2020', '4'],
...
```